# Sometimes PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options) returns zero results

Tags: ios, swift, phasset

Sometimes `PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)` returns nothing when there are **images and permission**.

This is sporadic, and is solved by force-quitting and restarting the iOS app.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Am I missing something critical like, "Sometimes you won't get images back because X?"

Here is my code:

```
func load() {
    ProgressIndicatorView.show(onView: self.view)
    PhotosPermissions.tryGetPhotosPermission(
        didSucceed: { [weak self] in
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                let options = PHFetchOptions()
                options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor.init(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
                options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d || mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue, PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
                options.includeAllBurstAssets = false
                let fetchResults = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: options)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?._assets = fetchResults
                    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                    print("Loaded \(fetchResults.count) images.")
                    ProgressIndicatorView.hide()
                }
            }
        },
        didFail: { [weak self] in
            ProgressIndicatorView.hide()
            self?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "OpenFormSegue", sender: self)
        }
    )
}
```

When the error occurs, the log line reads: `Loaded 0 images.`

Comment: I got a same problem by the user feedbacks(not happed for me).
Did you solve it?
How does it happen?